# Is there a rhetoric term for using a pejorative positively or a euphemism negatively e.g. to loosen moral assumptions?

Tags: negation, connotation

I'm not asking about contronyms or words that migrate from negative to positive connotations (e.g. "bad" or "gay")

Examples: "I don't meant to just name-call. I mean to name-call with surgical precision."
"I shame, you shame. I aim to shame where it helps more than harms."
"It's arrogant to declare someone arrogant as if you're the authority. My arrogance knows bounds."
"I admire a person who lies wisely."
"I think too much just the right amount."

"He was braver than he was smart."
"She's so proudly conservative she's a radical."
"Beware of her kind humility."
"No deed's too dirty for a saint like him."

I would think this is an important rhetorical trope but I can't find a name for it.

Comment: I think some of these examples need a bit more explanation. Are they about use of a particular word? If so, indicate the word, and maybe a bit of context as to why you think they're not straightforward use of language. You're not quite talking about [reappropriation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation) which is the reclaiming of hate speech but some would qualify as irony (ah, but what sort of irony?).

Comment: Isn't every last one said with sarcasm? Originally a New Yorker, I say that with admiration. No sarcasm there.

Comment: This is not relevant to the core of the question, but it is not clear why you think that *gay* has moved 'from negative to positive connotations'. The term was, in this sense, originally used by gay people themselves, and has then been gradually embraced by those who support them; it is generally not used by those who don't.

Comment: Stuart F: Yes, this is about flipping the +-connotation of particular morally loaded words or terms: Name call, shame arrogant, lies, "think too much" brave, "proudly conservative, "Kind humility" "saint".

Answer (score 1):

In general, making a statement where the latter part surprises or defies expectation would be called **paraprosdokian**, from the Greek *para-* (against) and *prosdokia* (beyond expectation) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian)). For example:

> I've had a perfectly wonderful evening, but this wasn't it. ([Groucho Marx](https://web.archive.org/web/20110109061130/http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_hb1397/is_3_17/ai_n45060415/))

The term is more general than just switching from positive to negative connotation or vice versa. For example, it also applies to *garden-path sentences*, sentences that lure readers into a misreading as the sentence defies an initial interpretation ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence)), as in this example:

> "The complex houses married and single soldiers and their families."

Most readers will initially read "complex houses" as a noun phrase, but the following words don't make sense with that. In actuality, "houses" is a verb, but you likely have to read the whole sentence and go back to understand that.

Many statements work against semantic expectation. For instance, in your own example,

> I don't meant to just name-call. I mean to name-call with surgical precision.

this defies expectation because "I don't mean to just name-call" might be taken as an apology for name-calling, but the next statement actually intensifies the behavior.

Comment: Given the opening, I thought for sure you were headed for *paradox*, which seems to fit some of the examples...

Comment: Thank you for these responses. "Owning it" is apt, as is moral paradox. "You shouldn't be judgmental" or "tolerate everything including intolerance" are self-negating which I take to expose that they're not moral principles but lifelong moral dilemmas (e.g. when to be judgmental vs. non-judgmental?). To expose the dilemmas, I find it useful to flip connotations, sometimes owning judgment, disowning tolerance. I get the sense from your responses that there may not be a technical rhetorical term for this kind of moral connotation-reversal.